# doing the reverse of date.getTime()

Tags: javascript

I am converting DateObject to string doing

```
   var date = new Date(); //Tue Nov 01 2016 17:00:48 GMT-0400 (EDT)
   var string = date.toString();  //Tue Nov 01 2016 17:00:48 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Now I want to convert the my string to date object.How can I do this?

```
   var dateObject = ??????
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates are very easy to convert. As a string:

```
var date = new Date();
var dateStr = date.toString();
var dateObject = new Date(dateStr);
```

As a number:

```
var dateNum = date*1;
dateObject = new Date(dateNum);
```